# ActionLinks doesn't always work in FireFox and Safari

Tags: asp.net-mvc, css, firefox, safari, actionlink

I've been learning the new ASP.NET MVC framwork lately and I've developed a test site for a friend who runs a "light café" in Sweden. The plan is to release it within a week or so after performing some final adjustments and fixing some security issues.

Yesterday I published the site to a webhost running IIS 6, so the first thing I had to do was to fix the issue of the extensionless URLs. I did this with the help from Phil Haack's blog post [ASP.NET MVC on IIS 6 Walkthrough](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/26/asp.net-mvc-on-iis-6-walkthrough.aspx)

Now I have run into another issue that works well in IE7 but not in Firefox 3 and Safari.

On the site I use a master page containing a "left content" with a menu. The menu consists of ActionLinks. The problem is that only the first (topmost) link works as a link, the others only look like links but they're unclickable. When I view the source everything looks good.

Has anyone come across a solution that fixes this, or do you maybe know what can cause this behavior? The link to the demo site is [Demo site](http://www.tarsius.se)

Help would be greatly appreciated since I want this to work on all browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "main" div is being placed on top of the "links" div so they can't be clicked.

Adding a:

float: right;

To the CSS for #main allows the links to be clicked.

Comment: Thanx Paul. I realize I need to sharpen my CSS skills.

Answer (score 1):

I would check your css file.  If you remove your css file from your include I think your links will work.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the position: relative in #main and it'll work